# If the selected answer is a hint, should the person asking edit the OP with the full answer?

Tags: discussion, hint, duplicates

Sometimes, a hint is all it takes to answer a question. So if the person asking selects that question and no full answer was provided, should the "asker" edit the original post with a full solution?

If an answer is already selected and the "asker" already solved the problem, there's no point for someone else to want to post a full solution, but what if the hint is not enough for someone else? If that someone has the same question, asking it would be a duplicate.

How can this be solved?

Comment: A teacher using hint as an answer should IMHO encourage the asker to post a full solution. If the hint leads to an exchange of comments, it is easy to tell when to insert this suggestiion. Not all the askers oblige, but it is their choice. Sometimes it is better for the answerer to fill in the details themselves - a judgement call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Editing an answer into the question is not a logical thing to do. It will confuse future readers: if you already have the solution, what is the question?

The logical thing to do is to click this button:

[image: button]

and post the solution there.

Comment: Should the "asker" do that then? Or should the rest of the people still post answers to not fully answered questions so that others can access to the full information?

My question is: Who's responsability is it?

Comment: @DarthGeek It's not exactly a *responsibility*. There is no threat of fine or imprisonment for leaving a question without a complete answer. Whoever is willing and able to post the full solution can do so. Whether they are the author of the question or not does not make much difference.

Comment: In that case, what to do when someone else posts the same question and is redirected to the old one? If the hint is not enough for him should his question be un-marked as duplicated? If so, would the original question be marked as duplicated?

Comment: @DarthGeek The purpose of marking questions as duplicates is to have answers to the same question in the same place. Suppose question A has a hint, and question B is a duplicate of A. Then those wishing to expand upon the hint should do so under question A.